# Is there a function that doesn't have a limit at infinity but its derivative does?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Is there a function that is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$, its derivative converges to $0$ as $x\to \infty$ but the function does not converge as $x \to \infty$, neither to a finite limit nor to an infinite limit?
If not, how can you prove that?

Thank you
Gal

Comment: Welcome to this site! When asking a question, please post any attempts or thoughts of your own on the problem as well as any additional context so users can better pinpoint how to help you. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for both the tip and the example

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider the function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ given by $f(x)=\sin(\log(1+x^2))$.
It does not have a limit at $\pm\infty$ but its derivative
$$
f'(x)=\cos(\log(1+x^2))\frac{2x}{1+x^2}
$$
goes to zero as $x\to\pm\infty$.

Let me add how I came up with this function:
First, $\log(x)$ tends to infinity as $x\to\infty$ but its derivative goes to zero.
To make it behave well in both directions and at the origin, we change $x$ to $1+x^2$; note that $\log(x^2)=2\log(x)$ so the asymptotic behaviour is essentially the same.
Now we have a function that goes to infinity at infinity but the derivative goes to zero.
If we compose this with a nice smooth function that does not have a limit at infinity, we should be done.
And indeed, the function $f$ given above works.